# Format Key values in dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the key values like this.

```
>>>dict.keys()
[('4', '12'), (('8', '9'), ('10', '11')), (('8', '10'), ('12', '14')), (('10', '11'), ('14', '15'))]
```

I want to format the key values so that it looks like this.

```
>>>dict.keys()
[('4', '12'), ('8', '9', '10', '11'), ('8', '10', '12', '14'), ('10', '11', '14', '15')]
```

The inner brackets are removed in the expected output. I tried converting the keys to a list and then formatting the values, but it didn't give the expected output.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

The values in the dictionary corresponding to the keys remain the same. Also, I want to change the key formatting directly in the dictionary instead of converting it to a list as this raises error in other parts of the code.

Input dictionary:

```
{('4', '12'): '-100', (('8', '9'), ('10', '11')): '10--', (('8', '10'), ('12', '14')): '1--0', (('10', '11'), ('14', '15')): '1-1-'}
```

Expected Output Dictionary:

```
{('4', '12'): '-100', ('8', '9', '10', '11'): '10--', ('8', '10', '12', '14'): '1--0', ('10', '11', '14', '15'): '1-1-'}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? For easier look up, what you are trying to do is `flatten` a tuple.

Comment: You'll find a partial solution over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: What should happen to the values then? Can you show us the whole dict?

Comment: Apply the solutions from the linked post to each of your keys; your keys are arbitrarily nested.

Comment: Here is the solution: `def is_nested_tuple(tupl):
  return any(isinstance(elem, tuple) for elem in tupl)

lst = [tuple(chain(*tupl)) if is_nested_tuple(tupl) else tupl for tupl in lst]`

Comment: If you also need to update the keys in the dictionary then you'd either have to delete the old key and set the value again for the new key, or use a dict comprehension to build a new dictionary with the transformed keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `chain()`

```
def is_nested_tuple(tupl): 
      return any(isinstance(elem, tuple) for elem in tupl) 

lst = [tuple(chain(*tupl)) if is_nested_tuple(tupl) else tupl for tupl in lst]
```

Output

```
=> [('4', '12'), ('8', '9', '10', '11'), ('8', '10', '12', '14'), ('10', '11', '14', '15')]
```

Comment: Their input is not regular, there are variable levels of nesting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, he need to use a function to check if the tuple has nested structure. Check the answer now.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut The function works as intended. However, this does not change the key formatting in the dictionary. I have edited the question to explain my issue better.

Comment: @Abhi, please add another question in order to answer it.